# AJAX autocomplete or autosuggest

Tags: .net, ajax, visual-studio-2008, autocomplete, autosuggest

I am trying to incorporate an ajax autocomplete/autosuggest control into my website and I am encountering all kind of issues.

I tried the *ajaxcontroltoolkit* but ran into a deadend there.

I would prefer not to get into jquery being I'm feeling overwhelmed enough as it is.

I found [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/AutoSuggestServerControl.aspx?msg=3645719#xx3645719xx) that worked great when I ran the solution he provided. I modified the datasource to my database. Then created my own temp solution and added the controls, references, etc. and it worked fine.

So then I tried incorporating them into my website and *it just won't work*. I type in the textbox and nothing comes up at all.

I've been staring at this all day and the only difference I can see is that because the project I'm working on is a website and not a .net project, it has no solution file and no namespace.  Otherwise, as far as I can tell, it's identical to my previous two attempts.

I left a message on the board at codproject but I'm starting to run out of time on this deadline and I'm feeling very stuck.

*Any help would be greatly appreciated.*

Comment: What kind of dead end did you gome to with the Ajax Control Tookit?  It works fine for me...

Comment: I really recommend looking at jQuery again. It's really a good solution.

Comment: Well, I stripped out all Ajax references and controls from the project and tried it one more time and it now seems to work.  Thank you for commenting.